# Issues with 'checked' attribute in 'input' form tags within PHP while loops

Tags: php, forms, input, checked

I'm using a html form to edit sql db, thus I would want to have the form display the value currently in the database. I'm Using a while loop to display all the sql rows. I simple radio button allowing user to chose between 'Listings' (shows as '0' in sql) or 'Recent Transactions" (shown as '1' in sql).

The radio buttons are not pre-filling the value from sqlas checked or not

```
<form name="edit listing" action="edit_list.php" method="post" id="edit_form" >
  <ul>
       <?php while ($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
           $transaction = $data['transaction'];
           $chkvalue='checked="checked"'; ?>
   <li>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Designation <h6>Required</h6></legend>
       <input name="transaction" type="radio" tabindex="11" value="0" <?php if ($transaction == '0') echo $chkvalue; ?> />
      <label for="listings">Listings</label>
       <input name="transaction" type="radio" tabindex="12" value="1" <?php if ($transaction == '1') echo $chkvalue; ?> />
      <label for="recent_transactions">Recent Transactions</label>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" formaction="edit_list.php" value="Submit Changes" />
</form>
   </li>
           <?php endwhile;mysqli_close($con);?>
 </ul>
```

The short php insert   is working, a little. My source code is looking something like this:

```
<input name="transaction" type="radio" tabindex="11" value="0"  />
 <label for="listings">Listings</label>
<input name="transaction" type="radio" tabindex="12" value="1" checked="checked" />
 <label for="recent_transactions">Recent Transactions</label>
```

But the radio button is not pre-filling. 
[image: radio button not pre-filling]

I've been poking at this all day, any suggestion here where problem could be would be extremely helpful

Comment: you have to write only `checked` not `check="checked"`!

Comment: this isn't filling either    <input name="transaction" type="radio" tabindex="12" value="1" checked />

Comment: Do a `var_dump($transaction);` and show us what you get, this way we can help you better

Comment: Taking your HTML as it is I don't have any issue getting the checked radio button to be checked by default.

Comment: @Crackertastic, I'm seeing now it has to be something with how my loop is set up with <ul><li></li></ul>, the radio check IS appearing in the very last one on the page, but none before that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have to write `checked` not `check="checked"`!

So change it to this:

```
$chkvalue='checked'; ?>
```

instead of this:

```
$chkvalue='checked="checked"'; ?>
```

Comment: here from source code:   <input name="transaction" type="radio" tabindex="12" value="1" checked />
              <label for="recent_transactions">Recent Transactions</label>    still nothing showing up checked on the page. thank you though @Rizer123

Comment: @rhill45 your sure? if i copy this: `<input name="transaction" type="radio" tabindex="12" value="1" checked />` in a html file it works fine for me!

Comment: It's something with my loop, I just noticed it shows a checked value in my last item but none before that

Comment: @rhill45 also your listed item (li) goes over the end form tag!? is that supposed to be?